# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound for an object, apparent routing bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I am a Rails newbie and am struggling with appears to be a routing bug.

I have a Site object that holds information about a website and how to crawl it. I want to test my code's connection to the site. Clicking "test site" in my app creates an error:

> ```
> Couldn't find Site without an ID
>
> app/controllers/sites_controller.rb:86:in `test_site'
> ```

**routes.rb**:

```
...
      post "/test_site" => "sites#test_site" 
      get "home/index"
      resources :sites, :logins
...
```

**index.html.erb**

```
...    
      <% @sites.each do |site| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <%= form_tag test_site_path(site) do -%>
            <div><%= submit_tag 'Test site' %></div>
            <% end -%>
...
```

**sites_controller.rb**

```
...
      def test_site
        @site = Site.find(params[:id])
...
```

It looks like the Sites controller is not getting a Site :id from test_site_path(site). I'm not sure how to setup routes and pass the ID correctly.

Thanks!

**Edit**: I tried adding this code to my routes.rb:

```
resources :sites do 
  get "/test_site", :action => "test_site", :on => :member 
end
```

I get this error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"sites", :action=>"test_site", :format=>#<Site id: 11, ...
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see that `post "/test_site"` takes an id. In any case, why not [add a RESTful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) and not worry about manually defining the route param?!

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried adding a RESTful action a few ways and have not figured out how to do it correctly. Would you mind posting the code to do that?

Comment: Add `get 'test_site', :on => :member` in the sites resource block.

Comment: @Dave Hi, I added this to my routes.rb:

resources :sites do
    get "/test_site", :action => "test_site", :on => :member
end

I get this error:

No route matches {:controller=>"sites", :action=>"test_site", :format=>#<Site id: 11, ...

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question rather than trying to stuff code into comments.

Comment: Curious why you didn't try following the example. Anyway, also make sure that `rake routes` returns what you think it should re: the path helper method. You can also test the path helper method from `rails c` as a sanity check. Also make sure you *remove* the old, incorrect path, and restart Rails to make sure it picks up the new routes.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I tried adding *get 'test_site', :on => :member* to routes.rb but that generated this error: _missing :action_. I then tried adding :action => "test_site" using the syntax in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

For a newbie the best thing I can tell you to do is to get in the process of writing a controller test when you are adding a new feature as it helps debug issue like this. Use restful actions instead of creating your own. Try to use index, new, edit, create, update, show, destroy instead.

sites_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SitesController do
  let(:site) { Site.create() } #Add to create what a site requires, eventually this will become a fixture but don't worry about that now
  describe "#show" do
   before { get :show, id: site.to_param }
   it "responds with success" do
     response.should be_success
   end
  end
end
```

Run this test. It will tell you that you have no route

routes.rb

> resources :sites, only: %w[show]

Run this test. It will fail and tell you to create a sites controller and a show action:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

Run the test again.  It will now complain because there is no view.

> View -> create directory (sites) -> inside create a file show.html.erb

Run the test again. It now is passing. Your routing is now working correctly, using REST, and checking that it is working is now automated.

This may seem a bit imitating right now, but I guarantee that if you make this a habit it will become second nature and you won't have to deal with routing bugs again.